# Can you use the expressions "my gears are grinding" when trying to say that you are thinking?

Tags: word-usage, idioms

If not, what other idioms could be used to express that one is thinking?

Comment: I've not heard it before, but it sounds a very good metaphor to me. "I will have to put my thinking cap on" would be one that I might use.

Comment: There's also [see someone's wheels turning](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/see-someone-s-wheels-turning) though IME it is usual to use this when refering to someone else rather than oneself.

Comment: When gears *turn*, they are working properly.  When gears *grind*, their relative speeds are incorrect and teeth are being broken off the gears, causing permanent damage that prevent them from working properly in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will be widely understood. It's likely to be confused with  [*to grind someone's gears*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grind+gears), which means

> To greatly or specifically irritate or annoy someone

An alternative is [*to rack one's brain(s)*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rack+brain):

> to think very hard, usually in order to remember something or to find a solution to a problem

<sub>(sources: The Free Dictionary)</sub>